# Magento 2.1 to 2.4 order migration

Tags: orders, migration, data-migration

we have upgraded a very buggy Magento 2.1.9 website to Magento 2.4.1 and are about to launch the new website. It's taken a few months to upgrade and build a new theme. but obviously the orders are now out of synch.

How can I migrate the orders from the 2.1.9 live site to the new 2.4.1 development site?

(I did look at the Aitoc import/export order extension, but the tech support guys were awful and after a month of them ignoring an installation issue, I have to start from scratch again).

Comment: what did you do in the end?

Comment: We used Ulmod's Order Import Export. It seemed to do what we needed. 

It's worth noting that you need to reset the order number in Magento if you've done any test orders on the new site. But if I recall, the order Id's were slightly out of synch on a few orders, this may have been due to cancelled or deleted orders. but we weren't worried as the invoice info was retained and this only seemed to happen on the occasional order.

Also, the new customer accounts were unable to be migrated across so we forfeited those, the most important were the orders.